# How can I remove Customer View tab for particular member group?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, blocks, customer

I'm new to Magento, and I'm having a hard time understanding a layout/rendering issue:

On the **Customers -> Manage Customers -> Click on a customer page**, it shows a list of tabs on the left side, one of which is called "Customer View". But when I look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs::_beforeToHtml`, I see that the function call to `addTab()` is commented out for the "Customer View" tab.

So where is the "Customer View" tab being added from? How can I remove "Customer View" tab for particular member group?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, I'd appreciate if you'd consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it...

Answer (score 1):

The customer view tab corresponds to the `Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` block. The tab is added in the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml` file, on lines 41-44:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="customer/tab/view.phtml">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
        </block>
        <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I'm not sure why the core team decided to comment out the code in the block and add it in this way instead.

To remove it for a specific customer group, there are a couple tactics you can use:

1) Listen to the `controller_action_layout_render_before` or `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event and in your observer file, remove the block from the layout object.

2) (Not recommended, but easier): rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` block, and specifically the `isHidden()` method with logic that specifies whether to show or not show based on the customer group.

Welcome to Magento, and good luck. It's pretty fun stuff.